# ActiveReports 7 Section Document Printing All Blank

Tags: vb.net

I'm using ActiveReports 7 PRO and cannot get the reports to print correctly. It sends the document to the printer however it's all blank. I'm needing to print a bunch of reports in a loop so I'm looking to do this all programmatically. Here's the code I'm currently using after the DataSource is set, etc:

```
rptPT.Run(True)
rptPT.Document.Printer.Print()
```

I can't seem to load it into a viewer in the loop and print it that way (nor do I want to) because it tells me that the report has not been loaded fully. Like I said, it prints, however it's just a blank page with nothing on it. Also: if I export it to a PDF everything is fine in the PDF document.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following forum post wherein similar issue has been discussed and resolved :
http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/printing-blank-pages-2/

See if this helps.

Regards,
Mohita